# Intercepting input entered into the Firefox developer console?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, console, firefox-developer-tools

I am currently in the process of moving my web-dev work from classic IDEs to the web browser console. The console is basically a JavaScript [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop), which is great, but that also means it can only process valid JavaScript expressions. Is there any way of redirecting the input to a custom processing function instead?

This would make it possible to integrate a custom [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) directly into the browser console and make it feel more like a native terminal. For example, the custom processor could translate an input of `log hello` to the valid JavaScript expression `console.log("hello")` and [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) it.

Right now the best solution I came up with is using a very short function name, e.g. `$('log hello')` or the slightly shorter [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax `` $`log hello` ``. Both solutions require at least three additional characters, even more keystrokes, and the input must be surrounded by quotes/ticks/braces.

I would definitely accept solutions involving browser extensions, as long as they integrate with the existing console or at least do not require a completely new implementation of the developer tools console tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

As you already wrote, the built-in functionality of the console only allows the [execution of JavaScript code plus some helper commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter).

And there are currently (as of Firefox 69) [no APIs for extensions to extend its functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions#JavaScript_APIs), only some to add new panels and a few other unrelated ones.

Comment: Thanks, that settles it for me. I have already looked into some of the APIs but was afraid I missed something. There is still the option of introducing some kind of hook in a custom fork, but that's something for when I am actually sure I want to continue down this path.